# (How) Do you test your dependencies in your unit-tests?

Tags: unit-testing

Should you include testing external dependencies in your unit-tests, eg. not mocking the objects in the dependency but actually creating an instance in your unit-test as to ensure some third party didn't do something stupid like creating a BC-break in a patch release. If so, how do you do this? I can assume that automatically instantiating external code could lead to serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Unit Test the classes that use the dependencies by mocking the dependencies. Avoid tight coupling to external dependency **implementations**. If there are no abstractions, wrap them in your own abstractions.

Comment: In what way does that test your dependencies. I don't see this as tight coupling, as your code depends on it in the same way (may it be interfaces or concrete classes). The main thing I would like to get some extra comfort in is that dependencies that update their patch version (symver) don't accidentally create a BC-break that will break your code when you update and are caught by the unit-test. Or should this be in another phase of the CI process?

Comment: You don't unit test your external dependencies. Unless you are doing integration test to verify expected behavior with your system, there is no need. The external dependency owners would have tested it before release.

Comment: Do you really trust that all other developers never make a mistake on whose work your code might have a (possibly unknown) dependency on?

Comment: No, which is why I do not tightly couple to their implementation concerns and ensure to perform integration tests to confirm expected behavior.

Comment: You asked specifically about unit testing. That is what my statements are directly referring to. It is not your responsibility to unit test external dependencies. There is nothing you can do about code you have no control over. The most you can do is report the bug. And then what?

Comment: Well what you could do is obviously report the bug, but since you caught the error before the code was merged into master you can revert a version and lock the package there until it's resolved. However it is clear to me that this should be part of your integration test-suite and not be part of the unit tests. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some great comments from @Nkosi I have come to the conclusion that this **should not** be a part of your unit-test suite. However to correctly test against deficiencies in external dependencies, integration tests should be set-up.

While looking into integration testing I came across a great answer about the balance between unit-tests and integration tests on StackExchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208458/when-should-i-write-integration-tests#answer-208465